# Amcharts v4 MySQL not show chart

Tags: mysql, amcharts

my chart is not shown. If I  copy  and paste query result  manually it works.
working code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <style>
        body {
            font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", Roboto, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif, "Apple Color Emoji", "Segoe UI Emoji", "Segoe UI Symbol";
        }

        #chartdiv {
            width: 90%;
            height: 500px;
        }
    </style>

</head>
<body translate="no">
<script src="./lib4/core.js"></script>
<script src="./lib4/charts.js"></script>
<script src="./lib4/themes/animated.js"></script>
<div id="chartdiv"></div>

<script id="rendered-js">

    am4core.useTheme(am4themes_animated);

    var chart = am4core.create("chartdiv", am4charts.PieChart3D);
    chart.hiddenState.properties.opacity = 0;
    chart.innerRadius = 100;
    chart.legend = new am4charts.Legend();
    var title = chart.titles.create()
  title.text = "Population grow in year (2020)";
    chart.data = [{"ID":"1","country_name":"Suomi","total_number":"100","year":"2020"},{"ID":"2","country_name":"Ruotsi","total_number":"200","year":"2020"},{"ID":"3","country_name":"Eesti","total_number":"50","year":"2020"},{"ID":"4","country_name":"Tanska","total_number":"417","year":"2020"},{"ID":"5","country_name":"Norja","total_number":"417","year":"2020"},{"ID":"6","country_name":"Islanti","total_number":"531","year":"2020"}];


    var series = chart.series.push(new am4charts.PieSeries3D());
    series.dataFields.value = "total_number";
    series.dataFields.category = "country_name";
</script>
</body>

</html>
```

this code not  show chart,
json_data is same as I have copied in working code sample  chart.data = [...]
In MySQL version I have added drop down to select years. It works and make queries right way and if
I copied different years results and add manually into above chart.data = [...] code works and chart show OK.
The copied data that I use is in below code json_data( I copied it from alert(json-data)
Also title shows right text and changed then I  change year in drop down

```
    <script>
function show_graph (json_data,year) {
  alert (json_data);
  am4core.ready(function() {
 

 
  var chart = am4core.create("chartdiv", am4charts.PieChart3D);
  chart.hiddenState.properties.opacity = 0; 

  chart.legend = new am4charts.Legend();
  var title = chart.titles.create()
  title.text = "Population grow in year (" + year + ")";
  chart.data = json_data;
  chart.innerRadius = 100;
  
  var series = chart.series.push(new am4charts.PieSeries3D());
 
  series.dataFields.value = "total_number";
  
  series.dataFields.category = "country_name";
  
  }); 
}
</script>
```

What is  wrong my  code?
It must  be this line chart.data = json_data;

Not see any error messages in console

picture of my  json data

[jsodata from MySQl](https://www.dropbox.com/s/759b525et5ddcpz/jsondata.png?dl=0)